# Remove parenthesis and Characters inside it

Tags: regex, string, dart

I want to remove parenthesis along with all the characters inside it...

```
var str = B.Tech(CSE)2020;

print(str.replaceAll(new RegExp('/([()])/g'), '');

// output => B.Tech(CSE)2020
// output required => B.Tech 2020
```

I tried with bunch of Regex but nothing is working...

I am using Dart...

Comment: Note that `replaceAll()` is already global, so the `/g` flag is probably redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Dart, you don't have to use the forward slashes `/` to delimit the pattern. You can use a string and prepend it with `r` for a raw string and then you don't have to double escape the backslashes.

In your pattern you have to:

- escape the parenthesis
- [negate the character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) to match any character except the parenthesis
- repeat the character class with a quantifier like `*` or else it will match a single character

The pattern will look like:

```
\([^()]*\)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qI7Yiw/1) | [Dart demo](https://tio.run/##DcmxCsIwEADQufmKo0vuRErpaHBQ6Q@om1UITbCBNAlnqIL47bHj4xnNuRQ3p8gZpFm1c1EqAWKJzsCsXUCCr6gWzfDKDHuoj83VjhOeLj11bdfWSlSJXci4fsM2eT3ag/cY7BvO9tl/ErIc8PZAum8GkrQFCZJIiV8pfw)

Example

```
var str = "B.Tech(CSE)2020";
print(str.replaceAll(new RegExp(r'\([^()]*\)'), ' '));
```

Output

```
B.Tech 2020
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Dart syntax is off, and seems to be confounded with JavaScript.  Consider this version:

```
String str = "B.Tech(CSE)2020";
print(str.replaceAll(RegExp(r'\(.*?\)'), " "));  // B.Tech 2020
```